# Increasing performance with DMA for SPI6

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, dma, dac

I am using the STM32H7 and the HAL libraries. On my board the SPI6 is used to communicate with an external DAC (DAC8734). The communication works perfectly fine (with DMA). The goal is to update the DAC every like 8µs to simulate an AC signal. For that I use the TIM15 basic timer. The timer calls inside of its interrupt the transmit function of the DMA. After completion of the transmission the buffer will get incremented in the DMA_Interrupt_Handler, as I am not able to continuously send data to the DAC (DAC needs and high/low trigger on the CS line for updating its channel). Is there any way to increase my performance?

here the code for TIM15:

```
__HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();
__HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE();
__HAL_RCC_BDMA_CLK_ENABLE();

TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef SClockSourceConfigDMA;
TIM_SlaveConfigTypeDef sSlaveConfigDMA;
TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfigDMA;
TIM_IC_InitTypeDef sConfigICDMA;

htim15.Instance = TIM15;                    //TIM15 must be synchron to TIM5         --> 40 MHz, Baseclock is 200 Mhz
htim15.Init.Prescaler = 300;//300;//15;         //Max. for good sin: Pre = 50 & Per = 16 & DIV4
htim15.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
htim15.Init.Period = 5;//4;                     //Period = 5 & Prescaler = 100 für 200 kHz -->
htim15.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
htim15.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE;
if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim15) != HAL_OK)
{
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
}

SClockSourceConfigDMA.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim15, &SClockSourceConfigDMA) != HAL_OK)
{
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
}

if (HAL_TIM_IC_Init(&htim15) != HAL_OK)
{
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
}

sSlaveConfigDMA.SlaveMode = TIM_SLAVEMODE_TRIGGER;
sSlaveConfigDMA.InputTrigger = TIM_TS_ITR2;
if (HAL_TIM_SlaveConfigSynchronization(&htim15, &sSlaveConfigDMA) != HAL_OK)
{
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
}

sMasterConfigDMA.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;
sMasterConfigDMA.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim15, &sMasterConfigDMA) != 
HAL_OK)
{
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
}

sConfigICDMA.ICPolarity = TIM_INPUTCHANNELPOLARITY_RISING;
sConfigICDMA.ICSelection = TIM_ICSELECTION_DIRECTTI;
sConfigICDMA.ICPrescaler = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
sConfigICDMA.ICFilter = 1;
if (HAL_TIM_IC_ConfigChannel(&htim15, &sConfigICDMA, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != 
HAL_OK)
{
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
}

if (HAL_TIM_IC_ConfigChannel(&htim15, &sConfigICDMA, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != 
HAL_OK)
{
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
}

if (HAL_TIM_IC_ConfigChannel(&htim15, &sConfigICDMA, TIM_CHANNEL_3) != 
HAL_OK)
{
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
}

if (HAL_TIM_IC_ConfigChannel(&htim15, &sConfigICDMA, TIM_CHANNEL_4) != 
HAL_OK)
{
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
}

__HAL_TIM_ENABLE_IT(&htim15, TIM_IT_UPDATE);
__HAL_TIM_ENABLE_IT(&htim15, TIM_IT_CC1);
__HAL_TIM_ENABLE_IT(&htim15, TIM_IT_CC2);
__HAL_TIM_ENABLE_IT(&htim15, TIM_IT_CC3);
__HAL_TIM_ENABLE_IT(&htim15, TIM_IT_CC4);

SystemCoreClockUpdate();
}
```

here the code for DMA:

```
//Setting the configuration for the DMA tx --> this is the configuration for         SPI6 as Trigger
hdma_spi6_tx_init.Instance                  = BDMA_Channel2;                        //Choose BDMA, for SPI6 is connected to DMAMUX2
//hdma_spi6_tx_init.DMAmuxChannel->CCR      = 0b1100;                               //Selects SPI6 for DMAMUX2
hdma_spi6_tx_init.Init.Request              = BDMA_REQUEST_SPI6_TX;                 //BDMA (DMAUX2) for TX of SPI6
hdma_spi6_tx_init.Init.Direction            = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;                 //Transfering from Memory to Peripherie (2, S.632)
hdma_spi6_tx_init.Init.PeriphInc            = DMA_PINC_ENABLE;                      //Incrementing the address register todo: maybe enable
hdma_spi6_tx_init.Init.MemInc               = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;                      //Incrementing the memory address register
hdma_spi6_tx_init.Init.PeriphDataAlignment  = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;                  //Data size: Byte, because SPI6 is transferring 8-Bit at the time
hdma_spi6_tx_init.Init.MemDataAlignment     = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;                  //Memory data size: Byte, because thats the size of the other registers
hdma_spi6_tx_init.Init.Mode                 = DMA_NORMAL;                           //Peripheral flow control mode (S.632)
hdma_spi6_tx_init.Init.Priority             = DMA_PRIORITY_VERY_HIGH;                   //High Priority for transfer
hdma_spi6_tx_init.Init.FIFOMode             = DMA_FIFOMODE_ENABLE;                  //Direct mode for transfer (todo:FIFO enable)
hdma_spi6_tx_init.Init.FIFOThreshold        = DMA_FIFO_THRESHOLD_FULL;              //Wait for full FIFO
hdma_spi6_tx_init.Init.MemBurst             = DMA_MBURST_SINGLE;                    //One byte sized burst for memory
hdma_spi6_tx_init.Init.PeriphBurst          = DMA_PBURST_SINGLE;                    //One byte sized burst for peripheral

//Setting the configuration for the BDMA (S.653 + S.663)
bdma_spi6_init.CPAR  = BDMA_REQUEST_SPI6_TX;            //Peripheral register address for SPI6
bdma_spi6_init.CMAR  = (uint8_t *) Crrct_Size_Buffer;   //Memory register address
bdma_spi6_init.CNDTR = 0xFFFF;//0x1F2;                  //Total number of data to transfer
bdma_spi6_init.CCR  |= 0x3098;
//  Bits for CCR           (0 << 15) ||             //Double-buffer mode off
//                         (0 << 14) ||             //Memory-to-memory mode off
//                         (1 << 13) ||             //Priority level high
//                         (1 << 12) ||             //Priority level high
//                         (0 << 11) ||             //Memory size: 8-Bit
//                         (0 << 10) ||             //Memory size: 8-Bit
//                         (0 <<  9) ||             //Peripheral size: 8-Bit
//                         (0 <<  8) ||             //Peripheral size: 8-Bit
//                         (1 <<  7) ||             //Peripheral as destination, enable Memory increment mode
//                         (0 <<  6) ||             //Memory as source, disable Peripheral increment mode
//                         (0 <<  5) ||             //Circular mode disabled
//                         (1 <<  4) ||             //Read from Memory
//                         (1 <<  3) ||             //Enable transfer error interrupt
//                         (0 <<  2) ||             //Disable half transfer interrupt
//                         (0 <<  1) ||             //Disable transfer complete interrupt
//                         (0 <<  0);

if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_spi6_tx_init) != HAL_OK)
{
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
}

__HAL_LINKDMA( hspi, hdmatx, hdma_spi6_tx_init);
```

Inside the TIM15_IRQHandler I call the DMA transmit:

```
    SCB_CleanDCache_by_Addr( (uint8_t *) Crrct_Size_Buffer, sizeof(Crrct_Size_Buffer)/sizeof(Crrct_Size_Buffer[0]));    //Clear memory space for TxBuffer

    HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA(&hspi6, (uint8_t *) Crrct_Size_Buffer, 3);
```

After transmission the BDMA IRQ Handler is called:

```
Crrct_Size_Buffer[0] = Crrct_Size_Buffer[IRQ_Counter[0]+3];                                                         
Crrct_Size_Buffer[1] = Crrct_Size_Buffer[IRQ_Counter[0]+4];
Crrct_Size_Buffer[2] = Crrct_Size_Buffer[IRQ_Counter[0]+5];

if(IRQ_Counter[0] < (NumberOfSamples-1)*3 )                                                                         
{
    IRQ_Counter[0] = IRQ_Counter[0] + 3;
}
else
{
    IRQ_Counter[0] = 0;
}

HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DAC_LDAC_GPIO_Port,DAC_LDAC_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);                                                   //LDAC high/low to update the command register
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DAC_LDAC_GPIO_Port,DAC_LDAC_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(&hdma_spi6_tx_init);
```

My problem is right now, that I don't really get any performance increase. I assume it is because I manually increment my Crrct_Size_Buffer, but I cant just send all the data at once, because of the DAC (which need its high/low trigger). Does anyone have any idea how to increase the performance?
If you need more information please don't hesitate to ask. Sorry for my bad English I am no native :)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The obvious solution would be to re-design the hardware and drop the DAC in favour of PWM + op amp. Why exactly do you need the DAC?

Comment: I am programming an Lockin-Amplifier and the hardware is pretty much fix (I am just a student working at the university). For the Locking we need a AC reference signal, which I should create with the DAC.

Comment: Ok then you don't need a DAC because it operates on the "secondary side" and the accuracy only needs to be as great as the specified output resolution. But if the hardware can't be changed, I guess it doesn't matter. A PWM + op amp would have removed the whole SPI latency.

Comment: Got an external crystal? What clock is the system clock running at? Your real-time spec is pretty tough, so I would imagine that you need maximum clock speed.

Comment: You are right, the accuracy is defined over the threshold frequency of the following low pass filter, which is 25 kHz. But either way i have to update the DAC with around 125 kHz, which slows my process too much. The base clock is 400 MHz, generated by an external oszillator. The SPI clock is 50 MHz, which is the maximum for both the SPI and the DAC. PWM + op amp sounds a lot better, but at this moment I have to try it with the hardware I have, unfortunately.

Comment: this is the classic example showing the damage caused by the HAL. **it is impossible** to program uCs without an elementary knowledge of the hardware used. I see that the OP has missed this step believing that the "magic" will sort everything out. And the result: horrible, illogical and incorrect code which can be replaced by 30 lines of the register settings.

Comment: Do you want to enlightend me on how the HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA function works? I never worked with DMA or HAL funtions before, so yes the concept is quite complicated to get on first glance (for the record I didnt choose to use HAL functions either)

Comment: @Sven All but the simplest questions regarding HAL seem to be unanswered on this site, or get referred to the examples shipped with the HAL library. IMO people tend to abandon it as soon as they realize how much it just gets in the way of doing things *efficiently*, so there are very few people with real experience using it, despite HAL being around for 5 years now. **The best way to solve performance problems is to abandon HAL, and working with the Reference Manual.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the STM32H7 SPI controller is capable of pulsing CS after every 24 bit frame on its own. The key parameters are the `DSIZE` field in `SPI->CFG1` and the slave select management bits in `SPI->CFG2`.

Setting `DSIZE` tells the controller the number of bits in one frame. Setting it to `23` (one less than the actual frame size) has two effects.

- When writing a full 32 bit `uint32_t` value in `TXDR` (transmit data register), the most significant 8 bits will be ignored, and 24 bits will be shifted out to the `MOSI` pin.
- `CS` can be pulsed after every 24 bit frame.

From the Reference Manual section *Slave select (SS) pin management*

> Hardware SS management (`SSM = 0`)
>
> SS output enable (`SSOE = 1`)
>
> ...
>
> c) When `SSOM=1`, `SP=000` and `MIDI>1` the SS is pulsed inactive between data
>   frames, and kept inactive for a number of SPI clock periods defined by the `MIDI`
>   value decremented by one (1 to 14).

If there were more data frames in the SPI transmit FIFO, it would start shifting out the next one, but there are no more, so it will wait for the next write to `TXDR`.

Now, writing a single 32 bit register every 8µs is sufficient to trigger the whole transmit sequence. It can be automated with a timer and a DMA channel, requiring no software interrupts for every transmit.

Set up the DMA channel to copy 32 bits from the memory buffer (which should be padded to 32 bits) to the SPI transmit register. **Have the DMA transfer triggered by a timer update event, not by SPI.** Set the timer to 125 kHz, and to generate a DMA request on update events (`UDE` bit in the `DIER` register).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am currently trying to change it, as you adviced. On first glance it seems to be faster. But I have one more question regarding the HAL functions. After using HAL_DMA_Start_IT to transfer from memory buffer to TXDR peripheral buffer, do I still have to use the function HAL_SPI_Transmit to start the SPI transfer? These HAL functions are kinda confusing using them the first time

Comment: @Sven I have no idea how to persuade HAL to do transfers triggered by a timer. Maybe it doesn't support this use case at all.